# I need to find links that contain the same number and merge them all into the same cell

Tags: textjoin

can someone help me speed up the process in excel. I need formula to find links that contain the same number and merge them all into the same cell. So far I've done it with the formula but it's a slow process for me when I have over 1000 links:
=TEXTJOIN( ", ";TRUE;B110:B114)

Thanks!

[Textjoin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qrUX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use several columns. 
Col B, extract the number from the strings with

```
=mid(A2,26,4)
```

Column C formula

```
=If(B2=B1, "", D2)
```

Column D

```
=IF(B2=B3, A2 & "," & D3, A2)
```

Copy those all the way down and answers with be in C. Filter out the blanks if you want.

Comment: That's it. Thanks bro :)
Only the comma remains on the last link, but that's not a problem;)

Comment: That's why I get trying to do it in my head... Please mark the answer correct if it worked.